# My Jquery Function Which Activates a Menu Wont Work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jquery function which activates another menu in my navigation bar. However it seems that my code isn't working can someone help me solve my problem?

```js
function change_active() {
  $('.side-nav-bar a').click(function() {
    $('.side-nav-bar a').removeClass();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-bar content">
  <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;" onclick="change_active()">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_active()">전공소개</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_active()">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_active()">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="change_active()">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `change_active()` doesn't activate the other menu, it installs a click handler that does that. So you have to click twice.

Comment: so im going to get this instead?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve here, but at least one thing is wrong here, each time you click, you set click handlers on your links that are stacking on each other, it means that the previous handlers are not removed and set again and again. Try to add a `console.log('test');` in your function and you'll see what i mean

Comment: I removed the change_active() already. now my problem is how can I make another menu active.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/1409x3dm/6/ check out this one fiddle

Comment: well, I can see that the add and remove class works but right now my problem is, I have already a CSS for the active menu. when I applied the code given by you, it didn't work.

Comment: then why didn't you update your CSS @AlexDeneris

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `change_active()` function. Just bind the event handlers in top-level code.

```js
$('.side-nav-bar a').click(function() {
  $('.side-nav-bar a').removeClass();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-bar content">
  <a class="active-menu" href="javascript:;">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
  <a href="javascript:;">전공소개</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">졸업 후 진로</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교육 프로그램</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">교수소개</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And if the user reload the page? The latest clicked menu must be activated :-)
To solve this, I use local storage to store the a key on each click

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".menu").click(function () {
            // Save the id of the current menu cliked
            // Into a key 'menu_id' in the localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("menu_id", $(this).attr("id"));
        });

        // Call this for each page reload
        // Set the active class to the related menu wich match with the local storage key
        $(function () {
            var main_link = $("#" + localStorage.getItem("menu_id"));
            main_link.addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-nav-bar content">
    <a class="menu" href="javascript:;" id="menu-1">체육학</a><i class="arrow right"></i>
    <a class="menu" href="javascript:;" id="menu-2">전공소개</a>
    <a class="menu" href="javascript:;" id="menu-3">졸업 후 진로</a>
    <a class="menu" href="javascript:;" id="menu-4">교육 프로그램</a>
    <a class="menu" href="javascript:;" id="menu-5">교수소개</a>
</div>
```